# Multiple kernels in cuda 4.0

Tags: cuda

Is  it possible to launch multiple kernels on multiple GPUs concurrently from a single thread in cuda 4.0?

Comment: Yes you can. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097994/789683

Comment: possible duplicate of [concurrent kernel execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097855/concurrent-kernel-execution)

Comment: I think the question is slightly different in that the question also includes multiple GPUs in single thread. Ofcourse both these questions have been handled in stackoverflow individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use multiple GPUs from a single thread, you can switch between cuda contexts (each of which is bound is bound to a GPU) and launch kernels asynchronously. In effect you will be running multiple kernels across multiple GPUs this way.

However if you have cards with compute capability > 2.0, you can also run kernels concurrently as shown in the comments above. You can find the post about [concurrent kernel execution over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097855/concurrent-kernel-execution).

Ofcourse you can use both if you have multiple cards with compute capability >= 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

yes.
If there are 2 devices you can run kernel1<<<>>> at device0 and kernel2<<<>>> at device1. there is an option setdevice() with which you choose the device on which the kernel will be executed.
google it, it is in the cuda library 4.0